# Batch script to edit a .txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a .txt document with over 32,000 lines of commented machine code. It looks like this:

```
Display menu window
C0/000E:    E220        SEP #$20       (Set 8-bit accumulator)
C0/0010:    C210        REP #$10       (Set 16-bit X and Y)
```

I have a script that converts it as follows for compiling purposes:

```
; Display menu window
SEP #$20       (Set 8-bit accumulator)
REP #$10       (Set 16-bit X and Y)
```

The problem is, I'd like to keep the first address of every function as a label. So it should instead look like this:

```
; Display menu window
C0000E: SEP #$20       (Set 8-bit accumulator)
        REP #$10       (Set 16-bit X and Y)
```

Specifically, that means I need a script that will:

1. Stop whenever the first 3 characters on a line are not C0/
2. Look at the next line; if it starts with C0/, continue, otherwise return to step 1. and skip the line.
3. Print a semi-colon at the start of the line. More info on this below.
4. Make it so C0/XXXX: becomes C0XXXX:
5. Delete the next 9 characters.
6. Print two spaces.

My other script will take care of the rest. I need the script to add a semi-colon because my actual script will add another semi-colon in front, so I'll be able to use find-and-replace to safely remove them both everywhere.

Note that this board automatically converts tabs into a number of spaces, so each line from the code I provided is not of the same length as that in my local file.

Comment: Show your code; someone could help modifying it to achieve your requirements then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you use batch files for text processing but here's a script that converts the first text block in your question into the third:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

>output.txt (for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%a in ('find /n /v "" input.txt') do (
    for /f "delims=] tokens=1*" %%b in ("%%a") do (
        set line=%%c
        if "!line!"=="" (
            echo:
        ) else if not "!line:~0,3!"=="C0/" (
            echo ; !line!
            set inblock=
        ) else (
            for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%b in ("!line!") do (
                if "!inblock!"=="" (
                    set inblock=1
                    set label=%%b&set label=!label:/=!
                ) else (
                    set label=
                )
                echo !label!    %%d
            )
        )
    )
))
pause
```

NB. Replace space(s) with a literal tab character between !label! and %%d in `echo !label!  %%d`.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are some problems with the output: 1. Blank lines are deleted. 2. Number of spaces is off (4 instead of 2 on a line with a label, and not enough on lines without a label).

Comment: I've updated the code to fix the first issue, but what spaces are you talking about? Haven't you seen the note under the code block?

Comment: I removed two spaces from "echo !label!    %%d", which fixed the spacing issue with labels. The line that has "REP #$20" isn't aligned with "SEP #$20". It only has two spaces preceding it instead of 9. But I managed to fix this by adding spaces after "set label=". So thanks a lot for the code!

Comment: Well, actually, all you had to do is insert *a literal tab character* between !label! and %%d instead of spaces, as the note says, and everything would be aligned just perfectly (implying the default tab size of 8).

Comment: Oh, I see. Somehow I thought your note had to do with restoring the tabs I mentioned in my original post. I don't want to use tabs in such a way because tab size varies depending on the word processor (e.g., WordPad).